# A specific test case will not pass the test somehow

Tags: c++, string, vector, token, erase

The purpose of the code is to basically remove the words inside the useless array that are present in a text file. I'm having this very odd problem where the code will not remove the word 'the' in the phrase 'waiting on the shelf', but every other test cases (a lot) passed. Any ideas?

```
int main(){
    string useless[20] = { "an", "the" , "of", "to", "and", "but", "nor", "or", "some", "any", "very", "in", "on", "at", "before", "after", "into", "over", "through", "along"};

    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    if(fin.fail()){
        cout << "Input failed to open" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    string line;
    getline(fin, line);
    getline(fin, line);
    getline(fin, line);
    getline(fin, line);

    ofstream fout("output.txt");

    while(getline(fin, line)){
        vector<string> vec;
        istringstream iss(line);
        while (iss) {
            string word;
            iss >> word;
            transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
            vec.push_back(word);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
                if(vec[i] == useless[j]){
                    vec.erase(remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec[i]), vec.end());
                }
            }
            fout << vec[i] << " ";
        }
        fout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Yes, yes I can see how a debugger would really help me here. I am currently not using any IDE (just sublime and terminal) hence the lack of a debugger.

Comment: You don't need an IDE to use a debugger - you can just use gdb from the command line.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to put more structure into your code by splitting the stuff in `main` into two or three **functions**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using incorrect iteration here

```
 for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
            if(vec[i] == useless[j]){
                vec.erase(remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec[i]), vec.end());
            }
        }
        fout << vec[i] << " ";
    }
    fout << endl;
}
```

Before this iteration you have vector with the next values: [waiting][on][the][shelf]. When i == 1 you delete "on" from the vector, so that you have the next vector [waiting][the][shelf], but ***i*** index still equal to 1, on the next iteration you skip "the" word because the last erase operation reorganized your vector and shifted "the" word to the deleted "on" position.

You can use remove_if. For example:

```
 vec.erase(remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&]( const string& str )
 {
     return std::find(begin(useless), end(useless), str ) != end(useless);
 }), vec.end());
```

After that you will get filtered vector, without words in the ***useless*** array.

By the way we can optimize that. The algorithm above has the next complexity: O(vec_size*useless_size). We can optimize it to O(vec_size) only.
Instead of array you can use hash collection (unordered_set) It gives you constant time for element access.

```
 unordered_set<string> useless = { "an", "the" , "of", "to", "and", "but", "nor", "or", "some", "any", "very", "in", "on", "at", "before", "after", "into", "over", "through", "along" };
 ...
 vec.erase(remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](const string& str)
 {
     return  useless.find(str) != useless.end();
 }), vec.end());
```

Comment: So a solution would be to reset the iterator every time an element is deleted? edit: or just decrements i each time an element is deleted?

Comment: I will write the solution in the answer.

Comment: You can write your own condition for std::remove_if method. For each element in vec i am trying to find element in the useless collection using std::find method. If I find it ( result of std::find is not equal to the end of array), I return true ( for std::remove_if predicate it means: delete element ).